# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am using **mysql v5.7** and **laravel 5.5**. When I try to "add product" the following error occurs.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a
>   default value

My **products** table

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->string('size');
            $table->string('price');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

My **ProductController** with **store** method

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //validation
    $this->validate($request,[
        'name'=> 'required',
        'description'=>'required',
        'size'=>'required',
        'price'=>'required',
        'image'=>'image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg|max:10000'
    ]);

    //image upload
    $image=$request->image;
    if($image){
        $imageName=$image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move('images',$imageName);
        $formInput['image']=$imageName;
    }

    Product::create($formInput);
    return redirect()->route('product.index');
}
```

When I add `->nullable` method to the field, there is no error but the data in table is null.

Please help me...

Comment: Is `$formInput` ever defined? As far as I can see it only has one key, which is image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never defined the validated data as a variable. Try this for validation.

```
$formInput = $this->validate($request,[
    'name'=> 'required',
    'description'=>'required',
    'size'=>'required',
    'price'=>'required',
    'image'=>'image|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg|max:10000'
]);
```

This will store all the validated fields within the variable `$formInput` as an array.

Comment: @BImoAnugrah there should be a checkmark underneath the arrows - click that.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have specified the name field in the $fillables in your model.

```
protected $fillables = [ 'name'];
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. May I suggest you edit your answer to provide code formatting by enclosing any code lines between ` characters or selecting the code block and pressing Ctrl+K